# How to delete files in folders and all subfolders which contain specific string in file name?

Tags: windows, file, cmd

I have folder where I have tons of other subfolders and each of them contains files like

- original_file1.jpg
- original_file1_t1.jpg
- original_file2.jpg
- original_file2_t1.jpg
- *and so on*

I would like to remove all of them from within Windows command prompt and I tried that with

```
del /s *_t1.*
```

But it is only removing files within folder that I am currently.

How to do this with code that will check every folder within this location?

The structure of folders looks like this:

- Main_folder/album_1/original_file1_t1.jpg
- Main_folder/album_2/original_file1_t1.jpg
- *and so on*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am so sorry for posting this thread but I found the solution.

When You are in your main folder just use

```
del /s /q *_t1.jpg
```